# Connect PHP with mysql database using mysql_connection

Tags: php, database-connection, wampserver

i need to know how to declare the database connection using mysql_connection in php 
and this is sample of code

```
    $password = "";
    $localhost = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->$localhost,$this->$username,$this->$password);
```

Note i am using wamp server

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code? Is this inside a class?

Comment: `$this->$localhost` etc. should be `$localhost`.

Comment: Use mysqli_ since you are just starting out, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php.

Answer (score 1):

Use mysqli instead. Start like this:

```
    $db = new MySQLi("host", "username", "password", "db");

    if(!$db)
    {
         die("your_error_msg" . mysqli_error($db));
    }

    $db->set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: Setting the character set is superfluous in your answer.